# Is it possible to have javafx webview capture desktop notification requests from webpages?

Tags: java, javafx

I know a number of webpages, such as Slack, Gmail, and Discord generate Desktop Notifications, and from [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-desktop-notifications-to-your-web-applications), I see that it can be done using javascript. Is it possible to capture those requests using javafx's webview and, for example, print out the text to the console? I can't find anything relating to this, so my guess is it can't be done, but if it can, it would make me a very happy programmer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that much into JavaScript and HTML, but in the [WebEngine Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) you can see that there are a few callbacks for some JavaScript functions. The methods you're looking for should be `window.confirm()` to accept notifications and `window.open()` to show the notification. These JavaScript methods can be handled by setting a `confirmHandler` and a `createPopupHandler`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on JavaScript, so I might be mistaken, but I believe window.confirm() would pop up one of those text boxes with an ok and cancel button, and window.open() opens a new window/new tab.